# validate answers in qualtrics using JS

Tags: validation, qualtrics

I am hoping to get some help validating the answers in qualtircs. I use the "constant sum" question type, and I am wondering whether there are ways to check whether the numbers people entered are factors of 2,000, and whether the sum of the numbers entered is 10,000. Ideally, if these validation failed, qualtrics should stop people from moving to the next page. Qualtrics can do the sum checking using its built-in validation option, but cannot simultaneously check whether the entered numbers are factors of 2000.

I've searched this site and tried to modify some of the codes pasted here but none worked.would really appreciate if anyone can help.

Comment: Are the only valid numbers 0, 2000, 4000, 6000, 8000 and 10000?

Comment: yes! you are exactly correct.

Comment: Why not just use custom validation then?